# How do I find out the current remaining lifetime of my AFS tokens?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, kerberos, openafs

I can use `klog` to renew my AFS token, but I am wondering whether there is an equivalent command to view the remaining lifetime of my AFS token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "tokens" command will show you whether you have an AFS token, and it also shows you the expiration time.

```
$ tokens

Tokens held by the Cache Manager:

User's (AFS ID 12345) tokens for afs@example.com [Expires Mar  2 23:59]
   --End of list--
```